# Hacer una transición suave entre un aside que se muestra y otro que no

Tags: javascript, css, html5, eventos, frontend

Quiero hacer que la transición entre la clase `show` y la `noShow`, sea suave.
Mi código es este:

```
<aside class="noShow" id='asideFiltros'>
            <h3>Filtros</h3>
            <h4>Ingrese el precio</h4>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Precio en $">

            <h4>Ingrese Marca</h4>
            <select id="marcas">
                <option value="audi">Audi</option>
                <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
                <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
                <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
            </select>

            <h4>Ingrese el orden de precios</h4>
            <select id="ordenPrecios">
                <option value="relevancia">Más Relevante</option>
                <option value="precioBajo">Precio más bajo</option>
                <option value="precioAlto">Precio más alto</option>
            </select>
        </aside>
```

Mi CSS es este:

```
#asideFiltros.show{
    transform: scale(1);
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #bada55;
    position: absolute;
    right: 21%;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: visibility 1s linear;
  
  }
  #asideFiltros.noShow{
    transform: scale(0);
    display: none;
  }
```

Y mi Javascript es este:

```
let filtros = document.getElementById('filtro');

filtros.onclick = () => {
    let aside = document.getElementById('asideFiltros');

    if (aside.classList.contains('noShow')){
        aside.classList.remove('noShow');
        aside.classList.add('show');
    }else{
        aside.classList.add('noShow');
        aside.classList.remove('show');
    }
}
```

Intenté con un `transform: scale` y con un `transform: translate`, pero ninguno me funcionó correctamente.  Alguna idea?

Comment: Pista: la propiedad `display` no se puede animar.

Comment: Y entonces como puedo hacer? Para que quede lindo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te dijeron en comentarios, la propiedad `display` no se puede animar, pero está la alternativa de usar altura máxima (`max-height`):

Si la pones en cero, el elemento no se mostrará ni ocupará espacio en pantalla, que es lo que buscas con `display: none;`.

Para que se muestre, cambias por un número igual o mayor a la altura que debe tener el elemento; si no la sabes, usa un número grande, teniendo en cuenta que puede afectar la forma en que se efectúa la animación.

Te propongo que uses una sola clase que puedas intercambiar fácilmente con [.toggle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) sin tener que analizar.

Solo necesitas asignar los estilos del estado oculto por ID y crear una clase `.show` para mostrar, donde solo cambies las propiedades necesarias.

```js
let filtros = document.getElementById('filtro');

filtros.onclick = () => {
    let aside = document.getElementById('asideFiltros');
    // Solo alterna la clase
    aside.classList.toggle('show');
}
```

```css
/* El elemento debe tener toda la configuración necesaria */
#asideFiltros {
    transform: scale(0);
    width: 30%;
    background-color: #bada55;
    position: absolute;
    right: 21%;
    padding: 10px;
    /* Aplica la transición a cualquier atributo disponible */
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    /* Ocultar y que no ocupe espacio en pantalla */
    max-height: 0;
}
#asideFiltros.show {
    transform: scale(1);
    /* Si no sabes la altura exacta asigna un valor alto */
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="filtro">
    Mostrar filtros
    <aside id='asideFiltros'>
        <h3>Filtros</h3>
        <h4>Ingrese el precio</h4>
        <input type="number" placeholder="Precio en $">

        <h4>Ingrese Marca</h4>
        <select id="marcas">
            <option value="audi">Audi</option>
            <option value="volkswagen">Volkswagen</option>
            <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
            <option value="Honda">Honda</option>
        </select>

        <h4>Ingrese el orden de precios</h4>
        <select id="ordenPrecios">
            <option value="relevancia">Más Relevante</option>
            <option value="precioBajo">Precio más bajo</option>
            <option value="precioAlto">Precio más alto</option>
        </select>
    </aside>
</div>
```